# How to manipulate Bitbucket repository with token?

Tags: git, oauth, mercurial, bitbucket

I followed this documentation to get a token value and a token secret from bitbucket:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/OAuth+on+Bitbucket

After that I want to push/pull to a given repo by using that token.

At Github I can use the token like this way:
https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens#step-2-clone-a-repository

My question is how can I use this kind of http authorization at bitbucket (mercurial/git)?

Comment: Since June 2015, this seems officially supported. I have edited my answer below accordingly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This [BitBucket page mentions](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/7735/allow-http-access-to-repositories-via#comment-19378911):

> We recently introduced OAuth 2 and also added the ability to use them as [HTTP Basic Auth credentials](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html#OAuthonBitbucketCloud-Cloningarepositorywithanaccesstoken).
>
> ### Cloning a repository with an access token
>
> Since add-ons will not be able to upload their own SSH keys to clone with, access tokens can be used as Basic HTTP Auth credentials to clone securely over HTTPS.
>
> ```
> git clone https://x-token-auth:{access_token}@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
> ```
>
> The literal string `x-token-auth` as a substitute for username is required.
>
> Our process is similar to GitHub, yet slightly different: the difference is GitHub puts the actual token in the username field.

See more at "[OAuth on Bitbucket Cloud](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html)", as suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965307/how-to-manipulate-bitbucket-repository-with-token#comment84443796_24967371) by [nick graziano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3533786/nick-graziano).

Comment: Now if we could just get JWT tokens!

Answer (score 37):

I used an App password which I created from the Bitbucket Cpanel under Settings -> Access management (sidebar) -> App Passwords. After I did this I cloned the repo by using my username and the new app password as follows:

```
https://[your_user_name]:[app_password]@bitbucket.org/[your_user_name]/[repo_name].git
```

Comment: The docs seem to have this wrong with the x-token-auth in place of the user name, as it does not work for me, but the link @Psymatix left above, works.

Comment: The second [your_user_name] could be the name of the user/group that is the owner of the repo.  So, if you are bubba, and the repo is owned by shrimpingcorp, the url would look like:
`https://bubba:[app_password]@bitbucket.org/shrimpingcorp/[repo_name].git`

Answer (score 13):

First of all: **only OAuth 2 tokens can be used to clone repos**

While unclear from this page, I've seen people try to use OAuth 1 access tokens. Unfortunately Git and Mercurial do not support OAuth 1 and so it is not possible to clone repos that way.

This is because OAuth 1 requires requests to be uniquely signed. The token itself is merely one of the input variables for the cryptographic signing process that git and hg do not support.

Now we did indeed recently add support for OAuth 2 which, despite its name, is a very different protocol and does not include cryptographic signing. As a result, OAuth 2 tokens can be used to clone over https.

Here's a dump of me creating a new OAuth 2 access/bearer token and using it to clone one of my private repos:

```
$ curl https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \
  -d grant_type=client_credentials \
  -u dqN7QFLwJEcHsHadYw:pzvZG25WEDqbm9aeUVRHtQRHgTRgDr9t
{
  "access_token": "He1rBW1eYAzmT3ePJcvYDtkIcF1Pb1izZHo8oqpKMEL5ivsku71qkjfumVgR2bWsCiRM7XeEmbVffxU92w==",
  "scopes": "repository email",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "pfcnxSpXNPAeTcYhcQ",
  "token_type": "bearer"
}
$ git clone "https://x-token-auth:JU5dAtlMD30BisLpDkIap7T18Ry9v6p0Xif4owkQUyen_rLx5_B3PjjeqhLhpde0ezR1wyGLeqYE2HA49A==@bitbucket.org/evzijst/crypt"
Cloning into 'crypt'...
remote: Counting objects: 26, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
remote: Total 26 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (26/26), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Now be aware that OAuth 2 tokens expire in an hour. After that they will cease to work. Depending on how you obtained the access token you may have a refresh token. You can use this refresh token to issue a new access token immediately before attempting to clone, to avoid expiration.

Comment: Do you know if Bitbucket has any plans to make non-expiring auth tokens? If I'm not mistaken, your remote repository URL will become invalid when your token expires, meaning you won't be able to perform any actions on the remote until you refresh for a new access token and update the url with that new access token. That's quite a nuisance for either the user or the developer of a GIT client to maintain on an hourly basis. Even if the GIT client handles everything properly, the repository will unusable in any other GIT clients the user uses after that hour passes.

Comment: Yes, we're currently adding non-expiring API tokens, which might be named "App Passwords" by the time we announce them (naming is still being discussed).

Comment: Is it possible to obtain access token without callback url? I receive invalid url "No callback uri defined for the OAuth client"  when using your example with curl request.

Comment: Here is everything in a single command line `git clone "https://x-token-auth:$(curl -X POST -u "[CONSUMER_KEY]:[CONSUMER_SECRET]" https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d grant_type=client_credentials | grep -Po '(?<="access_token": ")[^"]*')@bitbucket.org/[USER_OR_COMPANY]/[REPO_NAME].git"`

Comment: Here is a one-liner for `tcsh`:
``git clone https://x-token-auth:`curl -X POST -u "[CONSUMER_KEY]:[CONSUMER_SECRET]" https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d grant_type=client_credentials | grep -Po '(?<="access_token": ")[^"]*'`@bitbucket.org/[USER]/[REPO]``

Comment: @nazikus Just add callback url in your oauth consumer settings and try again, it won't really take you to that url when you request an access token.

Comment: @ErikvanZijst Hi! Is your method documented in bitubcket official documentation?

Comment: What of git pulling? How does one perform a git pull later?

Comment: @ErikvanZijst Four years later, whatever became of the non-expiring API access tokens?

Comment: @ArtoBendiken they were released years ago: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html

Answer (score 7):

To manipulate Bitbucket repository with **token**:

1. First you create an "Oauth" in access management section of your bitbucket account setting. This gives you a "Key" and a "Secret". You have done this bit.
2. Now using these Key and Secret you ask Bitbucket for a token. In my case I made a http request to `https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token`. I could do it with Curl or some Ajax library like this:

   ```
   curl -X POST -u "yourKeyHere:yourSecretHere"  https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d  grant_type=client_credentials
   ```

   alternatively, my http request was like this (using superagent in node) with my `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you can use postman:

   ```
   request.post("https://yourKeyHere:yourSecretHere@bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/      access_token").send('grant_type=client_credentials');`
   ```

   the result is like this:

   ```
   {
      "access_token": "blah blah blah HXAhrfr8YeIqGTpkyFio=",
      "scopes": "pipeline snippet issue pullrequest project team account",
      "expires_in": 3600,
      "refresh_token": "hsadgsadvkQ",
      "token_type": "bearer"
   }
   ```
3. Now that you have the "access_token", clone a private repo with it. But the url to your repo should be like this (keep the bracket around token):

   ```
   https://x-token-auth:{tokenHere}@bitbucket.org/yourRepoOwnerHere/RepoNameHere.git
   ```

Comment: Above description is false.

Comment: @SunilSharma really? Which bit of it? I've been using it.

Comment: `request.post("https://yourKeyHere:yourSecretHere@bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/      access_token").send('grant_type=client_credentials');`` not working

Comment: As of today I get an error message like "If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile." when I try to simply `git clone https://x-token-auth:{tokenHere}@bitbucket.org/yourRepoOwnerHere/RepoNameHere.git`. Hoping this works with plain-old API endpoints in their v2 API.

Comment: I took off the .git and put double quotes around the whole URL and bingo!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a fairly old thread, but, just in case, I wrote my own credential store to manage bitbucket's token:

https://github.com/gildas/git-credential-bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all recommendations from this page, they all don't work on premise. It only works like this:

```
git clone -c http.extraHeader='Authorization: Bearer MDM0MjM5NDc2MDxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' https://bitbucketserver.com/scm/projectname/teamsinspace.git
```

Read official documentation: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html#HTTPaccesstokens-UsingHTTPaccesstokens